# GridSplitter not working when used in Grid present in DockPanel

Tags: wpf, xaml, dockpanel, gridsplitter

I am stuck in resolving the GridSplitter to work.I have a DockPanel which has a Grid which is DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" and I have a GridSplitter which is also DockPanel.Dock="Bottom".

But the GridSplitter is not working and not allowing to resize the layout.
Maybe I am doing is completely wrong.Please correct me and tell me how can I perform this GridSplitter functionality.

Here is the Xaml I have:

```
 <DockPanel Name="DocMain" LastChildFill="True">
  <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">

            <ScrollViewer Style="{StaticResource NotificationRegion}">         

                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource NotificationTextBlockStyle}" Name="Notification_Block"
                     Text="{Binding TxtBlkNotificationBar}"/>

            </ScrollViewer>

 <GridSplitter DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="Black" Height="2" Width="Auto" ResizeDirection="Rows" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
  </Grid>

</DockPanel>
```

Comment: As I know, to get `GridSplitter` start working, you need specify a not fixed `Width` and `Height` properties for Controls which in Panel. For example: use Width="Auto", or using MinWidth and MinHeight for `TextBox`.

Answer (score 2):

Gridsplitter only works inside the grid its supposed to be splitting, for example

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" BorderBrush="black" BorderThickness="5"/>
    </Grid>
```

makes a grid with 3 columns with 2 columns for content and one for the splitter, gridsplitter is specified to be inside column #2 and resize the cells its placed between.

Comment: See my edit..Now I have the GridSplitter inside the Grid but still its not working.Its not resizing.